# I need to add information from a .csv file in this OR exchange code

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this link that changes the AD user from OU through information coming from a .csv file.

In my IT structure, the information `regiao` and `diretoria` are the information that must also be contained in the Department field of the ad user.

How do I get the information and reuse it in the variables?

```
`Department = $região + ", " + $Diretoria`




Import-Csv -Path  C:\Users\leonan.martins\Desktop\teste2.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $target = [string]::Format(
        "OU={0},OU={1},OU={2},DC=lab,DC=suporti,DC=local",
        $_.Regiao, $_.Diretoria, $_.Area
       
    )
    Get-ADUser $_.User | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $target
    Write-Host "OUs dos usuários ALTERADAS!"
}
```

Comment: [1] PLEASE do not put info in the Comments. put it in the Question where it belongs. ///// [2] you built the OU with a string formatting operation ... so use the same to build the new value for the Dept. field and assign it to the object with the usual `Set-ADUser` cmdlet and `-Department` parameter. ///// [3] do you REALLY need ps3 and ps4? if not, please remove the unused versions.

Comment: hi Lee, thanks for the tips, I'm new here on SO. I will use your help.

Comment: thank you for fixing items [1] & [3]. [*grin*] ///// does this work >>> `$NewDepartment = '{0},{1}' -f $Regiao, $Diretoria` to build the new value? if it does  ... then use it in a `Set-ADUser`  call.

Comment: perfect Lee ! thanks

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to move the AD Object but also, set it's `Department` attribute, in which case you could either first set the user's attribute and then move it to the target Organizational Unit or vice-versa. You can use `-PassThru` to return the object you are working with which allows you to complete both operations in a streamed pipeline:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\leonan.martins\Desktop\teste2.csv | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $target = [string]::Format(
            "OU={0},OU={1},OU={2},DC=lab,DC=suporti,DC=local",
            $_.Regiao, $_.Diretoria, $_.Area
        
        )

        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.User -Department ('{0},{1}' -f $_.Regiao, $_.Diretoria) -PassThru |
            Move-ADObject -TargetPath $target

        Write-Host "OUs dos usuários ALTERADAS!"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! i keep forgetting about the `-PassThru` parameter ... [*grin*]

Comment: in some cases is nice to have @Lee_Dailey as long as there is no over engineering obsession to do everything with pipelines right :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - yep ... i do tend to whine about folks who insist on working everything thru long, convoluted pipelines ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i know, i feel the same there is some sort of obsession with pipelines and thinking it's better to use them instead of some classic approach but whatever people be people :P